# Ubuntu 22.04: Able to ping the host but no internet access on browser

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, ethernet

I am new to ubuntu. I have VM Virtual box installed on Windows system which launches the Ubuntu 22.04.

My system is connected to Ethernet and is able to access the internet (with Windows 10). When i try to access the internet on ubuntu browser it fails.

I am able to ping the host from the Ubuntu terminal but not able to access the internet. What is that need to be done/configured to do so.
Note: I am able to access the browser in ubuntu through mobile tethering but fails with ethernet.

Regards,
Sukesh

Comment: This is more a question related to the Windows network / firewall configuration and / or the configuration on the virtual network interface of Virtualbox. It's not really an Ubuntu-related question.